# Using was versus were

Tags: usage

Which one do I use for this sentence?

"I would be jealous if John was/were kissing another girl."

I'm guessing "were" would be the correct choice?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct and have similar meaning.

Using "were" forms a subjunctive. In the past the unreal part of an "if" sentence had to use the subjunctive.  In modern English it is not required.

Both "were" and "was" are correct and mean the same.  Using "were" is rather more formal, and perhaps less appropriate for the casual tone of the sentence.